# Move to next object in array after a ping failed response

Tags: ios, objective-c, loops, ping

I'm in the process of writing an application that pings multiple objects. I do this by creating an array, then loop through that array. I return a ping result per object. However, if a particular object fails to receive a response ping, SimplePing loops back around, pings the objects until it reaches the failed object, then it keeps looping on that.

Now, here is my question. How can I proceed onto other objects after getting to a failed object?

Here is some sample code on what I have so far as well as some logs.

```
-(void)beginConnectivitySetupAndTests {

    NSArray *arrayOfIPAddresses = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"10.0.0.1", @"10.0.0.2", @"10.0.0.3", @"10.0.0.4", @"10.0.0.5", nil];

    for (int i = 0; i<[arrayOfIPAddresses count]; i++) {

        if (self.ping != nil) {
        } else {
          assert(self.ping == nil);
            (self.ping = nil);
        }
        assert(self.ping == nil);

        NSString *individualObjectIP = [arrayOfIPAddresses objectAtIndex:i];
        self.ping = [[SimplePing alloc] initWithHostName:individualObjectIP];            
        assert(self.ping != nil);

        self.ping.delegate = self;
        [self.ping start];
        do {
            [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
        } while (self.ping != nil);
    }
}

-(void)simplePing:(SimplePing *)pinger didStartWithAddress:(NSData *)address {
    [self.ping sendPingWithData:nil];
}

-(void)simplePing:(SimplePing *)pinger didSendPacket:(NSData *)packet sequenceNumber:(uint16_t)sequenceNumber address:(nonnull NSString *)address {
    pingTimeoutTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(timerFired:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    _dateRef = [NSDate date];
}

- (void)timerFired:(NSTimer *)timer {
    NSString *failedHostnameString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.ping.hostName];
    // Move to next host

    [self beginConnectivitySetupAndTests];
}


-(void)simplePing:(SimplePing *)pinger didFailToSendPacket:(NSData *)packet sequenceNumber:(uint16_t)sequenceNumber error:(NSError *)error {
    [self.pingTimeoutTimer invalidate];
    pingTimeoutTimer = nil;

//    self.ping = nil;
}

-(void)simplePing:(SimplePing *)pinger didReceiveUnexpectedPacket:(NSData *)packet {
}

-(void)simplePing:(SimplePing *)pinger didReceivePingResponsePacket:(NSData *)packet sequenceNumber:(uint16_t)sequenceNumber address:(NSString *)address {
    assert(pinger = self.ping);
    [pingTimeoutTimer invalidate];

    NSDate *end = [NSDate date];
    double _latency = [end timeIntervalSinceDate:_dateRef] *10;

    self.ping = nil;
}

-(void)simplePing:(SimplePing *)pinger didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    assert(pinger == self.ping);
    [self.ping stop];

    self.ping = nil;
}
```

Here is the corresponding logs.

```
2016-07-15 09:47:56.462871 pingSimply[1536:597333] 64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time = 0.017010 ms
2016-07-15 09:47:56.473984 pingSimply[1536:597333] 64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time = 0.057189 ms
2016-07-15 09:47:56.705777 pingSimply[1536:597333] 10.0.0.3 Failed
2016-07-15 09:47:56.812671 pingSimply[1536:597333] 64 bytes from 10.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time = 0.995070 ms
2016-07-15 09:47:56.816320 pingSimply[1536:597333] 64 bytes from 10.0.0.2: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time = 0.020010 ms
2016-07-15 09:48:56.952408 pingSimply[1536:597333] 10.0.0.3 Failed
```

So now that you (may) understand my situation, and you see how I'm going through my For Loop with the Do - While statement...any suggestions as to how I can proceed onto pinging 10.0.0.4 and 10.0.0.5 after receiving no response on .03?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE!!

I figured out where I failed to add some critical code. I needed to first invalidate the SimplePing TimeoutTimer, then set `self.ping = nil;` within the `-(void)timerFired:(NSTimer*)timer` Method.

So the edited method should look like this:

```
- (void)timerFired:(NSTimer *)timer {
    NSString *failedHostnameString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.ping.hostName];
    NSLog(@"Host %@ not reachable", failedHostnameString);

    [pingTimeoutTimer invalidate];
    self.ping = nil;
}
```